# halt on compilation error in a sqlplus script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am deploying pl/sql code using several sql files that are called with `@@file`. If a package got a compilation error the script continues to the end.

Is there a way to stop on every compilation error?

I tried `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE` but the script still continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No native sql*plus way I'm aware of. Only workarounds. Like this:

```
20:42:50 TEST@oars_sandbox> get scr
  1  whenever sqlerror exit rollback
  2  create or replace procedure my_failed_proc as
  3    i number;
  4  begin
  5    select 1 into i from me_iz_not_exist;
  6  end;
  7  /
  8  @check my_failed_proc
  9  create or replace procedure my_correct_proc as
 10    i number;
 11  begin
 12    select 1 into i from dual;
 13  end;
 14  /
 15* @check my_correct_proc
20:42:57  16  .
20:42:59 TEST@oars_sandbox> get check
  1  declare
  2    l_status varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    select status into l_status
  5      from all_objects where object_name = upper('&1');
  6    if l_status = 'INVALID' then
  7      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Object &1 is invalid!');
  8    end if;
  9* end;
20:43:02  10  .
20:43:04 TEST@oars_sandbox> @scr

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Object my_failed_proc is invalid!
ORA-06512: at line 8


Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```