# Need to get error/warning when building a PL/SQL package with Ant

Tags: oracle, ant

Using the following I can compile a PL/SQL package.

```
<exec executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true" errorproperty="exit.status" logError="true">
    <arg line="MyUser/MyPassword@MyDatasource"/>
    <arg value='@C:\public\data_svn\trunk\DataBase_Scripts\packages\FSMP_PACKAGE.pkb'/>
</exec>
```

But if it has an error it still records a successful build. I have tried to get error codes out of the exec, but get nothing – or 0, success or not.

I also tried
    `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.CODE;`
and
    `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT WARNING SQL.CODE;`

But no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know java and not sure that understood what you want, but: compiling packages always goes without errors. Compilation error is not a SQL or PL/SQL exception. Maybe you can analyze output messages?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742715/halt-on-compilation-error-in-a-sqlplus-script

Comment: This is not a Java issue, or an issue with the PL/SQL creating an error message. We are running an Ant script that builds a PL/SQL package. If the package fails to build the Ant script still issues a 'success'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searches and experimentation I found the solution.
Basically you have to use `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT WARNING SQL.CODE' and capture the error by  querying the USER_ERROR table. Based on http://grokbase.com/t/ant/user/048v9ah8eq/compiling-pl-sql

```
<target name="RunExec">
    <exec executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true" errorproperty="exit.status" logError="true">
        <arg line="domain/secret@datasource"/>
        <arg value='@${buildPackage.sql}'/>    
    </exec>
```

In the buildPackage.sql

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT WARNING SQL.CODE
    @C:\packages\FSMP_PACKAGE.pks
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        NUM INTEGER;
        ERROR_TEXT USER_ERRORS.TEXT%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT Count(*) INTO NUM FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE Type
        = 'PACKAGE' AND NAME = 'FSMP_PACKAGE';
        If num > 0 Then
            SELECT TEXT INTO ERROR_TEXT FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE
            Type = 'PACKAGE' AND NAME = 'FSMP_PACKAGE';
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, ERROR_TEXT, True);
        End IF;
    END;
END;
/
@C:\packages\FSMP_PACKAGE.pkb
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        NUM INTEGER;
        ERROR_TEXT USER_ERRORS.TEXT%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT Count(*) INTO NUM FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE Type
        = 'PACKAGE BODY' AND NAME = 'FSMP_PACKAGE';
        If num > 0 Then
            SELECT TEXT INTO ERROR_TEXT FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE
            Type = 'PACKAGE BODY' AND NAME = 'FSMP_PACKAGE';
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, ERROR_TEXT, True);
        End IF;
    END;
END;
/
```

Note that `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT WARNING SQL.CODE` gets no semi-colon, as it’s a SQLPlus directive and there needs to be a slash between packages.
The script will halt at the first error, but we use this for test deployment so the packages should have worked in our development database.